# Posicionar cursor de un textfield a la derecha del texto que ya contiene

Tags: javafx, cursor

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación JAVAFX donde el usuario tiene varios textfields para rellenar y editar. Quiero que si entra a un nuevo textfield saltando de otro pulsando TABULADOR el contenido del textfield no esté seleccionado y además el cursor esté a la derecha. Los textfields tienen un oyente de eventos que detecta cuando reciben el foco y he ido probando varios métodos de la API para posicionar el cursor y deseleccionar contenido cuando se entra al textfield, por el momento, todos sin éxito.

¿Dónde está mi error?

```
id_ip2B_tf.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {

            if (newValue) {
                // 1 - sin funcionar
                id_ip2B_tf.deselect();
                id_ip2B_tf.positionCaret(id_ip2B_tf.getLength());

                // 2 - sin funcionar
                id_ip2B_tf.end();                   
            }
        }
```

Comment: Quieres que al entrar al `textfield `, el cursor se posicione a la derecha de texto? Has probado con `jTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);`?

Comment: no es un JTextField, es un textField de javaFX, no me aparece el método setHorizontalAligment. Te agradezco la respuesta.

Comment: He encontrado esto `textField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);`

Comment: no hace lo que busco. Alinea todo el contenido del textfield. Realmente no ajusta el cursor. Gracias por la ayuda Mario.

Answer (score 1):

Tras horas y horas de busqueda encuentro esta solución que no acabo de entender. Es necesario que se ejecuten los cambios de la interfaz en un hilo aparte. Confuso para mi.

```
id_ip2B_tf.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (newValue) {

                Platform.runLater(
                        new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                id_ip2B_tf.end(); // ahora si!!!
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    });
```